# something wrong with my dynamic array

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic

while add more than 13 element, the result seems to be not correct!
my code is below! when add 12 elements, the result is

> the NO.0 is 0
>   the NO.1 is 1
>   the NO.2 is 2
>   the NO.3 is 3
>   the NO.4 is 4
>   the NO.5 is 5
>   the NO.6 is 6
>   the NO.7 is 7
>   the NO.8 is 8
>   the NO.9 is 9
>   the NO.10 is 10
>   the NO.11 is 11

When add one more, the result is changed a lot, I have no idea what's going on here:

> the NO.0 is 0
>   the NO.1 is 1
>   the NO.2 is 2
>   the NO.3 is 3
>   the NO.4 is 4
>   the NO.5 is 5
>   the NO.6 is 6
>   the NO.7 is 7
>   the NO.8 is 0
>   the NO.9 is 1
>   the NO.10 is 2
>   the NO.11 is 3
>   the NO.12 is 12

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct dynarray myarray;
struct dynarray {
    int size;
    int length;
    int *array;
};

myarray *create(void) {
    /* TODO: define for arrays */
    myarray *da;
    da = malloc(sizeof(myarray));
    da->size = 0;
    da->length = 3;
    da->array = (int *)malloc(da->length * sizeof(int));
    return da;
}


void add(myarray *array, int val) {
    int i;
    int length = array->length;
    int size = array->size;
    int *temp;
    //printf("da->size1 = %d\nda->length1 = %d\n",array->size,array->length);

    if (size == length) {
        temp = (int *)malloc(length * sizeof(int));
        for (i = 0; i<size; i++) {
            temp[i] = array->array[i];
            printf("%d,", array->array[i]);
        }


        //printf("!@#$@#$=%d\n",array->length);

        array->array = (int*)realloc(array->array, sizeof(int)*length);
        for (i = 0; i<size; i++)
            array->array[i] = temp[i];
        array->length *= 2;
        length *= 2;
    }
    if (size <length) {
        array->array[size] = val;
        printf("array[%d]====%d\n", size, array->array[size - 1]);
        array->size++;
    }
}


int main() {
    int i;
    myarray *da = create();
    //printf("da->size = %d\nda->length = %d\n",da->size,da->length);

    for (i = 0; i<12; i++)
        add(da, i);
    // printf("a->size = %d\nda->length = %d\n",da->size,da->length);
    for (i = 0; i<12; i++)
        printf("the NO.%i is %d\n", i, da->array[i]);
}
```

Comment: What language is this?  C? C++?

Comment: I changed it to C tag because it's more likely to be a C program.

Comment: Memory leak of `temp`.

Comment: Should not `array->length` in `add` function change before realloc?

Comment: What @Tahlil said.  You're never actually growing the array.  In addition there's no need to use the temp array at all, realloc keeps the values in the original array.

Answer (score 1):

As said in comments, you're misusing realloc and not editing the length correctly.  Here's what add should be:

```
void add(myarray *array, int val){
    int length = array->length;
    int size = array->size;

    if(size == length){
        array->length *= 2;
        array->array=(int*)realloc(array->array,sizeof(int)*length);
    }
    array->array[size] = val;
    array->size++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, now l know what's going on here. and i know it's a little bit late to respond, this is my first thread in this website, so many awesome people here. and i apologise for being late!

Answer (score 0):

1. The `realloc()` in the previous answer isn't right as it uses the old
   length value
2. There are also some missing `malloc()` and `realloc()` checks (can return `NULL`)
3. `realloc()` doesn't require copying elements from old array in

Here is the code as I would write it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define INIT_LENGTH 3

typedef struct dynarray {
    int size;
    int length;
    int *array;
} myarray;

myarray *create(void) {
    myarray *da;

    da = (myarray *)malloc(sizeof(myarray));
    if (da != NULL)
    {
        da->size = 0;
        da->length = INIT_LENGTH;
        da->array = (int *)malloc(da->length * sizeof(int));
        if (da->array == NULL) {
            free(da);
            da = NULL;
        }
    }
    return da;
}

void add(myarray *da, int val) {
    int size = da->size;
    int length = da->length;
    int *ra = da->array;

    if (size == length) {
        length *= 2;
        ra = (int *)realloc(da->array, length * sizeof(int));
    }
    if (ra != NULL) {
        da->array = ra;
        da->length = length;
        da->array[size] = val;
        da->size++;
    }
    else {
        puts("Warning: failed to realloc() extra space, array size unchanged");
    }
}

int main() {
    int i;
    myarray *da = create();

    if (da == NULL) {
        puts("Initial alloc failure");
        exit(1);
    }

    //printf("da->size = %d\nda->length = %d\n",da->size,da->length);

    for(i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        add(da,i);
    // printf("a->size = %d\nda->length = %d\n",da->size,da->length);
    for(i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        printf("the NO.%i is %d\n", i, da->array[i]);
}
```